# How to update/store Image from picturebox to database (MS Access2007)

Tags: vb.net

can anyone help me how to update/edit some image in picturebox to database ms access 2007?

im using this code :

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

        Dim myCommand As New OleDbCommand
        Dim SQL As String
        Dim ms As New System.IO.MemoryStream
        Dim bmpImage As New Bitmap(PictureBox1.Image)

        Try
            If Not con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then Open_Koneksi()

            SQL = "UPDATE tb_pegawai SET nama=@nama, tgl_lahir=@tgl_lahir, gender=@gender, jabatan=@jabatan, alamat=@alamat, telepon=@telepon, foto=@image  WHERE nik=@nik"
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nik", TextBox1.Text)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nama", TextBox2.Text)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tgl_lahir", DateTimePicker1.Text)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", jk.Text)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jabatan", ComboBox1.Text)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@alamat", TextBox4.Text)
            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telepon", TextBox5.Text)

            bmpImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
            bytImage = ms.ToArray()
            ms.Close()

            myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", bytImage)

            MsgBox("Data saved")

            myCommand.Connection = con
            myCommand.CommandText = SQL
            myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()

            Data_Load()
            con.Close()

        Catch myerror As OleDbException
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & myerror.Message)
            Button1.Enabled = False
        Finally
            con.Dispose()


        End Try
    End Sub
```

when I run the program, did not get an error or anything.
but the picture does not appear on ms access

Comment: Your query is wrong.  Access doesnt use named parameters as such - parameters must be added in the order they appear in the query.  You should also use `Add` for all of them rather than AddWithValue

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to write the code?

Comment: For example, your "@nik" should be added last, since it's the last parameter in your query.

Comment: thank you very much for your help, now the program can work properly

Answer (score 0):

Access is able to work with parameters. I've used it countless times. My base functions for an access update query adds parameters like this:

```
Dim parameter As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@parameterKey", parameterValue)
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
```

You should also create your connection beforehand. This is my well tested solution for an access update function.

```
    Function UpdateACCDB(ByRef connectionString As String, ByVal table As String, ByVal ColumnsAndValues As Dictionary(Of String, Object), ByRef whereColumn As String, ByRef whereParameter As Object)

    table = "[" + table + "]"
    Dim sqlStatement As String = "UPDATE " + table + " SET "

    Dim rowsUpdated As Integer = 0

    For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In ColumnsAndValues

        sqlStatement += "[" + pair.Key + "]" + "=" + "@" + pair.Key + ","
    Next

    sqlStatement = sqlStatement.Substring(0, sqlStatement.Length - 1)

    sqlStatement += " WHERE " + whereColumn + "=@WHERE" + whereColumn

    Using connection As New OleDbConnection(connectionString)

        Dim command As New OleDbCommand(sqlStatement, connection)

        ''Set parameter for columns to be updated
        For Each pair As KeyValuePair(Of String, Object) In ColumnsAndValues
            Dim parameter As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@" + pair.Key, pair.Value)
            command.Parameters.Add(parameter)
        Next

        ''Set parameter for where clause column
        command.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("@WHERE" + whereColumn, whereParameter))
        Try
            command.Connection.Open()
            rowsUpdated = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            command.Connection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Throw ex
        Finally
            If Not IsNothing(command) AndAlso Not IsNothing(command.Connection) AndAlso command.Connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                command.Connection.Close()
            End If
        End Try
    End Using
    Return rowsUpdated
End Function
```

As you can see the columnNames and their values are provided as a Dictionary.